# how to override mailchimp button css

Tags: css, mailchimp

I am trying to override mail chimp css 
if I add inline css like

```
<input type="submit" value="SUBSCRIBE" background: #111; name="subscribe"  id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
```

this is working fine.

In this case, I am unable to use :hover along with mc-embedded-subscribe id. 
I mean if I write

```
#mc-embedded-subscribe .button {
    background: #222;
}
```

This is not working, also

```
#mc-embedded-subscribe input.button {
    background: #222;
}
```

is not working.

Please let me know how to make color change on hover for subscribe button in mailchimp,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `!important` to ensure your [background](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) rule isn't being overridden.  Is something else has higher [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) your CSS will be ignored.

```
#mc-embedded-subscribe:hover {
  background: #222 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS code is set to find a child (.button) of #mc-embedded-subscribe.   When really, they are the same thing as the button has a class and id.

Just do:

```
#mc-embedded-subscribe {
    background: #111;
}

#mc-embedded-subscribe:hover {
    background: #555;
}
```

See here:  http://jsfiddle.net/UteLC/3/

If that isn't working, you may need to add the `!important` so that your css overrides the default MailChimp css like this:

```
#mc-embedded-subscribe:hover {
    background: #555!important;
}
```

Comment: it didnt really work for mailchimp form button
Only thing that worked for me is adding an inline style sheet to the input button itself. In this case I have overridden the back ground color but unable to add :hover rule to the button itself.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it possible for you to share a link to the page you are working on?

Answer (score 1):

Just add "!important" at both places, it worked for me.

For example:

```
#mc-embedded-subscribe {
    background: #111!important;
}

#mc-embedded-subscribe:hover {
    background: #555!important;
}
```

You can see it live at [this blog](http://www.noderock.com/).

Just click on any post and look at the sidebar for the redesign in action.

Hope this helps.